# What is the meaning of 'a little too + adjective'?

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage, phrases, phrase-choice, adjective-phrases

What is the meaning of the phrase **"a little too + adjective"** ? 
For example:

> This is a little too hard for me.

Does it mean same as:

> This is slightly hard for me.

?

How are the following sentences different from the above sentence ?

> 1. This is a little hard for me .
> 2. This is little hard for me.

Comment: You have already asked this question [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/178276/meaning-of-the-phrase-a-little-too).

Comment: I think it would be very helpful for you to review the usage of "too" first. Take a look at number 2a in M-W [here](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/too). I also provided an alternative duplicate, "too late".

Comment: Also, if you're going to ask a similar question, please explain what you've learned since the last question and try to distinguish the current question from the previous one. Otherwise, it will be considered a duplicate, and too many duplicates are considered "noise" on SE.

Answer (score 0):

"This is a little too hard for me" **DOES NOT AT ALL MEAN** "This is slightly hard for me."

The first means that I cannot do it but that I could do it with only a small amount of assistance. The second means that I can do it on my own without much difficulty.